# Add "read full article" link when an article exceeds the word limit by using the "text helper" class in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the text helper class in CodeIgniter and want to create an if/else-statement to check if an article is longer than, let's say, 20 words so that I can add a "read the full article" link when articles exceeds this limit. However, I'm not sure how to proceed using this particular function and if it's even possible without creating a new function. Any ideas on how to resolve my issue?

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach ($company_reviews as $review) {
    $rating = $review->company_reviews_rating;
    $comment = word_limiter($review->company_reviews_comment, 10);
 ?>
<div class="review-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="/member/?id=<?= $review->id;?>"><?= $review->first_name; ?> <?= $review->last_name; ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <?php echo get_stars($rating); ?>
      <h4><?= $review->company_reviews_title; ?></h4>
      <?= $comment; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter is an optional suffix added to the string. By default it adds an ellipsis.

```
$comment = word_limiter($str, 10, '...<a href="">read full article</a>');
```